# HTML hyperlink stops at spaces in filepath

Tags: html, excel, vba, email, hyperlink

When sending an email via a VBA code I have written, the filepath being sent in the body of the email stops at the first space. I believe I have the right amount of quotations around it, but its still coming up short.

Also, is anyone aware of a quick fix so that it includes the signature of the user sending the email?

```
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo Cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("M").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "M").Value) = "no" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            strbody = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                        "You still have outstanding work on the Rescan Spreadsheet " & _
                        " Title number:  " & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value _
                        & "<br>" & "<br>" _
                        & "<A href=" & "\\cv-vfl-d01\dlr_office\Operational Teams\RR Scanning Team\Back file QA Xerox\Document Rescans\Rescans 2019" & ">Click here to open file location</A>"



            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value
                .CC = "Bethany.Turner@Landregistry.Gov.uk"
                .Subject = "Re-Scan Reminder"
                .HTMLbody = strbody
                .Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

Cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Reminder Sent", vbOKOnly   
End Sub
```

Following the display of the message, when you click the hyperlink, it stops and provides an error message saying `\\cv-vfl-d01\dlr_office\Operational` cannot be located.

Comment: hi. the quotes u use are only for vba. u need to put double quotes. try with "<A href=" & ""\\cv-vfl-d01\dlr_office\Operational Teams\RR Scanning Team\Back file QA Xerox\Document Rescans\Rescans 2019"" & ">Click here to open file location</A>"

Comment: FYI `On Error GoTo 0` is effective starting at the 2nd iteration of that loop - `GoTo Cleanup` can only happen if an error is raised in the 1st iteration, any error in any other iteration is going to be unhandled. You might want to move `On Error GoTo Cleanup` inside the loop block - or better, move the email-body creation to its own function, and move the email-item creation to its own function as well, each with their own error handling.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use ampersands between the href= and the file name, but you do need to add an extra double-quote:

```
"<A href=""\\cv-vfl-d01\dlr_office\Operational Teams\RR Scanning Team\" & _
"Back file QA Xerox\Document Rescans\Rescans 2019"">Click here to open file location</A>"
```

HTML requires the url to have quotation marks around the link. If this was a normal string in HTML it would look like:

```
<a href="\\my file path\">My link name</a>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the `Chr()` function to place the double-quote character in your string if it helps you:

```
"<A href=" & Chr$(34) & "\\cv-vfl-d01\dlr_office\...
```

Comment: Or use single-quotes around the path.

Comment: You make an excellent point @TimWilliams. I always forget that html allows single quotes to define their strings.